# Different output results from arcmap and python

Tags: python, arcmap

This is my first question and also my first trial to use python coding for image processing.
I am trying to calculate different vegetation indices from UAV images using python to fasten the process. The problem that when I compared the output files from arcmap and python code there was some differences. First, the images from the python code are shifted from the original Geo-position. Secondly, the files are much larger in size.
So, my questions are:

- Is the code below OK or it can be enhanced?
- why the output files are double the size ?
- Why the output images Geo-locations are slightly shifted?

Thank you for your help.

Python code :

```
import os

import rasterio

import numpy as np

input_path = r"Z:\NewDeal\Input"

outDir = r"Z:\NewDeal\output"

for f in os.listdir(input_path):
    if f.endswith(".tif"):
        name1=f[:4]

        raster = rasterio.open(os.path.join(input_path, f))

        blue = raster.read(1).astype('float64')

        green = raster.read(2).astype('float64')

        red = raster.read(3).astype('float64')

        np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

        #thies are the vegitation ideceis calcuilations
        ExG = 2*green - red- blue

        ro_name = "ExG"+ name1 +".tif"

        outPath = os.path.join(outDir, ro_name)

        output_name = rasterio.open(outPath,'w',driver='Gtiff',
             width= raster.width, height = raster.height,

             count=1, crs= raster.crs,

             transform=raster.transform,

             dtype='float64')

        output_name.write_band(1,ExG)

        output_name.close()

print('End of calculation and output')
```